# C++ - Checking whether two substrings are equal using hashing

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, data-structures, hash

I'm taking a coursera course and one of the assignment is to process large number of queries(upto the order of 10^6) to check whether two substrings are equal or not from a single string(maximum length of string is 500000) using polynomial hashing. A single query includes index a and b and length l.
I've implemented a code that pre-computes hashes for the whole string twice(for two seperate modulo-n numbers) and computes two hashes for each substring. This is to reduce the number of collisions.
The code:

```
class Solver {
string s;
unsigned long long x, m1, m2;
vector<long long> h1, h2;

public: 
Solver(string s) : s(s) {
    // initialization, precalculation inside constructor
    h1.resize(s.size() + 1); //first array to store precomputed hashes 
    h2.resize(s.size() + 1); //second array
    x = 263; // random multiplier for polynomial hash and 0 < x < m1, m2
    m1 = 1000000007;
    m2 = 1000000009;
    h1[0] = 0, h2[0] = 0;
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= s.size(); ++i) {
       h1[i] = ((x * h1[i - 1]) + s[i - 1]) % m1;
       h2[i] = ((x * h2[i - 1]) + s[i - 1]) % m2;       
    }
}
bool ask(int a, int b, int l) {
    if (a + l > s.size() || b + l > s.size())
        return false;
    long long y = 1, z = 1;
    y = (long long)pow(x, l) % m1;
    z = (long long)pow(x, l) % m2;
    long long H1 = (((h1[a + l] - (y * h1[a])) % m1) + m1) % m1;
    long long H2 = (((h1[b + l] - (y * h1[b])) % m1) + m1) % m1;
    long long H3 = (((h2[a + l] - (z * h2[a])) % m2) + m2) % m2;
    long long H4 = (((h2[b + l] - (z * h2[b])) % m2) + m2) % m2;
    return ((H1 == H2) && (H3 == H4));
}
};

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0), cin.tie(0);

    string s;
    int q;
    cin >> s >> q;
    Solver solver(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        int a, b, l;
        cin >> a >> b >> l;
        cout << (solver.ask(a, b, l) ? "Yes\n" : "No\n");
    }
}
```

sample output:

```
trololo
4 // number of queries
0 0 7 // a  b  l
2 4 3
3 5 1
1 3 2
yes
yes
yes
no
```

The code works for the above example. But when input for a is given as 0 and b a random value such that
on paper it's the right answer but the code outputs the wrong one and also for certain trivial strings like "abcabc", the code outputs the wrong answer.
example:

```
abcabcabc 
4
0 3 3
1 7 2
2 8 1
1 4 4
no
no
no
yes
```

Where am I going wrong when a = 0 and are my trivial inputs like "thethethe" valid?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie trust me coming here was a last resort. I've been debugging for a while and I believe the problem is the underlying math in the code. Since it involves huge numbers, I'm not able to figure out which part is wrong.

Comment: Break up the math and see where it's overflowing, underflowing, or just plain wrong by stepping through the the revised program with a debugger and checking all of the math as you go.

Comment: As for the math, the problem is when a = 0, hashes of the both strings differ by at least a factor of 10. The problem doesn't appear when both a and b is equal to 0.  I've been trying to find a solution for that particular case, tweaking around but no solution has come up.

Comment: I'm not sure hashing is adequate for determining the equality of two strings.  If the number of bits in the hash is lower than the number of bits in the string, it's definitely impossible.  The best you could hope for is to say with some probability that they *might* be equal.

Comment: 1 billion X 1 billion comes very close to overflowing a 64-bit number.  What size are your ull numbers?  NM, seems your algorithm wants to use overflow as it is just a hash?

Comment: I think that overflow is being taken care by mod operation for small strings and I'm not worried about large strings as of now. Also in the precomputed arrays for hashes, h[0] = 0 and I think it's making the calculation differ for a = 0. Not able to find a workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is 500k in length, then there are hundreds of billions of substrings - far too many to prehash in advance and fit in memory.

Instead of doing that, you should create hashes from every starting point of length 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...  There should only be on the order of 10 million of those.

And now given two substrings we can compare at least half of each of them with a single lookup.  Which makes the comparison take logarithmic time.

Comment: Another idea might be to precalculate substrings greater than length ~4 that are after it.  For "abcabcabc", you'd precalculate that index0 had a two matching substrings: index 0 of length 9, index 4 of length 6.    If the user enters `0 4 3`, you immediately know the answer is yes, because of the second precalculation. If the user enters `0 7 3`, you have to check location 7 at query time, but only 3 bytes at most.

Comment: A rough approximation suggests a sting of 500k in length of 26 random letters would have almost every combination of letters up to length 6 (26^6=308,915,777), which means each entry would have ~4 entries on average. Hm. 32 bytes of data + 12 bytes of vector overhead ~2GB of memory :(. More than I'd hoped.

Comment: @btilly the code prehashes individual characters of the string and when the query for the substring comes up, the starting index of the substring scales with the multiplier 'x' to the power of 'L'. In the worst case the running time is length of the string as well as the space taken with size of each hash limited to the mod numbers.

Comment: @mooing duck that's the problem. The precalculation is working with every index except 0 unless both a and b are 0 since they get the same hash numbers. I think the problem is that h[0] is 0 and is not scaling well enough to be equal to the hash of the second substring.